# JQuery show div when select list is chosen

Tags: jquery

i have the following jQuery script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choices").change(function(){
        $("select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($("#choices").attr("value")=="A"){
                $(".church").show(slow);
                $(".orginization").hide(slow);
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

and the html:

```
<select id="choices">

                <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                <option value="A">Church</option>
                <option valie="B">Non-Profit</option>
                <option valie="C">School</option>
                <option valie="D">Commercial</option>
                <option valie="E">Other</option>

                </select>
```

when i select church from the list which has value "A" it should unhide a div with class "church" but i can't get it to happen. could you tell me what is wrong with my script.

Comment: Is the variable _slow_ defined? If not, then you should be putting that in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass 'slow' to those methods, Instead you must specify a number. Read more on [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/show/) website.

**Updated:**

Another problem is that you must get the value of select element with **val** method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choices").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == "A"){
          $(".church").show(50);
          $(".orginization").hide(50);
      }
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: i have ( .hide(50); but it still will not work is there anything wrong with the script?

Comment: is there another way of writing the script?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choices").change(function(){
        var thisVal = $(this).val();     
        if(thisVal=="A"){
                $(".church").show('slow');
                $(".orginization").hide('slow');            
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/juekqwns/

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

http://api.jquery.com/show/

beside this, should pass a string, also need to re-write your js code.

```
   $(".church").show('slow');
   $(".orginization").hide('slow');

duration (default: 400)
Type: Number or String
A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
```

**JS**

```
$("#choices").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="A"){
    $(".church").show('slow');
    $(".orginization").hide('slow');
  }
});
```

demo in [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/7m9a9103/)

Comment: Glad it works for you and will appreciate if I can get some credit.

Comment: if I want to do the same hide/show for the other div.'s can I daisy-chain this script for the other selections?